# Pass additional data via POST from django template submit

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

Using Django template to display a table of `input text`.

But in the `view` only input out of this table are present in the `request.POST`. Dynamically created input are not available in the `POST`.

test.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' id="subscription-form">
....
....
<tbody class="draggable-column">
    {% for product in products %}
    <tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">{{forloop.counter}}</td>
        <td class="hidden-xs">{{product.title}}</td>
        <td class="hidden-xs">{{product.weight}}</td>
        <td class="" >{{product.yearly_consumption}}</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="{{product.id}}_jan" data-id="{{product.id}}_jan" class="user-action"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="{{product.id}}_feb" data-id="{{product.id}}_feb" class="user-action"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="{{product.id}}_mar" data-id="{{product.id}}_mar" class="user-action"></td>
         ......
         ......
         <td><input type="text" id="{{product.id}}_total" data-id="{{product.id}}_total" readonly="readonly" class="total-quantity"></td>
     </tr>
     <input type="hidden" value="{{product.weight}}" id="{{product.id}}_weight">
     <input type="hidden" value="{{product.is_winter}}" id="{{product.id}}_winter">
     {% endfor %}
</tbody>
....
....
</form>
```

This table input are not avalable in the POST of django view.

How could make this available in the POST?

Comment: None of your inputs have a `name` attribute, so they will not be included in the `POST` data. You need to specify a `name` attribute for all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to mention the `name attribute` to each of the `input tags`

```
<tr>
   <td class="hidden-xs">{{forloop.counter}}</td>
   <td class="hidden-xs">{{product.title}}</td>
   <td class="hidden-xs">{{product.weight}}</td>
   <td class="" >{{product.yearly_consumption}}</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="{{product.id}}_jan" data-id="{{product.id}}_jan" name="{{product.id}}_jan" class="user-action"></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="{{product.id}}_feb" data-id="{{product.id}}_feb" name="{{product.id}}_feb" class="user-action"></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="{{product.id}}_mar" data-id="{{product.id}}_mar" name="{{product.id}}_mar" class="user-action"></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="{{product.id}}_total" data-id="{{product.id}}_total" name= "{{product.id}}_total" readonly="readonly" class="total-quantity"></td>
 </tr>
     <input type="hidden" value="{{product.weight}}" id="{{product.id}}_weight" name="{{product.id}}_weight" >
     <input type="hidden" value="{{product.is_winter}}" id="{{product.id}}_winter" name="{{product.id}}_winter">
{% endfor %}
```

or put any kind of name you find suitable for your purpose

Comment: Thank you that works for me. If there is 10 products how can i put this all in django form variable?

Comment: make a name and add some dynamic values to them, or keep the same name for all the input, you will get them in request.POST

Comment: How could this dynamic values to declare in djanfo form as form variable. otherwise invalid form will execute.